# PHP - Fetching only one row if there is more results for two conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to display only the latest one of those rows which match to my conditions. It will be a conversation listing page where I would like to display only the latest message from the user or his/her partner, and then display the next conversation's latest message between the user and another partner, and so on...

I have this database:

[image]

And this code to fetch data:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=dbname", 'root', '');    

$stmt4 = $db->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM messages
    WHERE messages.from_id=7
        OR messages.to_id=7
    ORDER BY msg_id DESC
    ");
$stmt4->execute();
```

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: Apply a LIMIT 1 clause to your SQL if you only want one result returned

Comment: The screenshot here doesn't really convey much information. If the schema is relevant please post the details from `SHOW CREATE TABLE` in the question.

Comment: f I use LIMIT, it would select only one row, right? But I need to select only one row of EVERY conversation. So, if there are multiple rows of (from_id = 20 and to_id = 7) and (from_id = 7 and to_id = 20), then I would like to display only the latest of them. But if there is another conversation too (f.e. from_id = 7 and to_id = 8, and from_id = 8 and to_id = 7), then I would like to show the latest row of that one too, and continue showing last messages from every existing conversation. Maybe I was not clear enough because others answered the same, sorry for that @MarkBaker

Comment: @tadman I explained it a little bit more in the previous comment

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
select  * 
FROM messages
WHERE messages.from_id=7
    OR messages.to_id=7
ORDER BY timesent DESC
LIMIT 1
```

That should work per your requirements, it will only pull in the top record for what is matching your where clause and it will be ordered by the latest time sent.

Comment: Slightly different syntax, sorry. but yes then Limit 1

Comment: If I use LIMIT, it would select only one row, right? But I need to select only one row of EVERY conversation. So, if there are multiple rows of (from_id = 20 and to_id = 7) and (from_id = 7 and to_id = 20), then I would like to display only the latest of them. But if there is another conversation too (f.e. from_id = 7 and to_id = 8, and from_id = 8 and to_id = 7), then I would like to show the latest row of that one too, and continue showing last messages from every existing conversation. Maybe I was not clear enough because others answered the same, sorry for that

Comment: @BiróNorbi Ah, yes this wasn't super clear in your original question. I'll try and find some time to get back to answering this better today, still shouldn't be a hard task.

Answer (score 0):

You only need add LIMIT 1 to your query.

```
SELECT *
 FROM messages
 WHERE messages.from_id=7
   OR messages.to_id=7
 ORDER BY msg_id DESC
 LIMIT 1
```